# How do I automate an input answer in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

So I have been working on a simple batch file, that thanks to @Magoo, I was able to solve the first question I had about it. 
Now my next question, 
Is there a way to automate an answer input.
Since I'm running Windows 7 (this is the current course I am on, in my quest to become a knowledgeable IT guy), I cannot use PowerShell to extract an image, and to my best knowledge, PowerISO is the only program I have found where I can use command lines in a batch file to extract the .iso file that I want, and place it on the drive/directory that I want. However, I came across the need to input an answer 'NoAll' before I could finish the extraction. I'm wondering if there is a way to automate that answer, if needed. It will only be used once, as the NoAll implies.
All the code is correct and the batch file works properly barring this one little hiccup. 
Here's my batch file.

```
echo
cd "C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools"
call copype amd64 "C:\winpe-amd64" 
copy "C:\winpe-amd64\winpe.wim" "C:\winpe-amd64\iso\sources\boot.wim"
copy "C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\amd64\imagex.exe" "C:\winpe-amd64\iso" & cd "C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\amd64"
oscdimg.exe -n -bC:\winpe-amd64\etfsboot.com c:\winpe-amd64\iso c:\winpe-amd64\winpe-amd64.iso
cd 'C:\program files\powerISO"
piso extract "C:\winpe-amd64\winpe-amd64.iso" / -od f:
```

as the extract begins to run, I get a prompt for input, and this is where I would like to be able to automate the 'NoAll' answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All you're doing is typing the string "NoAll" once you get to the `piso extract` line?

Comment: That's correct. Once I run the extract operation on the piso extract line, the program runs, and if it comes up with a duplicate or something it's trying to overwrite (which I don't want) then it prompts me to input a "Yes/No/YesAll/NoAll" value to continue. After I have inputted the value "NoAll" it continues and finishes. And after testing to see if the whole batch worked properly, it did. So it's just that input automation I'm trying to figure out. @SomethingDark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all you need to do it input text, you can simply `echo` what you want to type and then pipe it to the other command.

```
echo NoAll|piso extract "C:\winpe-amd64\winpe-amd64.iso" / -od f:
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you! :) I ran the echo command and it ran the extract program without need for input. Then I verified that all the files that needed to be there were, and tested the USB by booting to it, and everything worked the way it should! Thanks! @SomethingDark

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input file and input redirector '<' to automate most of input. For example, create a text file 'NoAll.txt' with the content "NoAll" (without quotes, and add a newline at the end for 'Enter' key). On the command that needs NoAll, execute it as follow:

```
piso extract "C:\winpe-amd64\winpe-amd64.iso" / -od f: < NoAll.txt
```

Comment: A temp file is a bit excessive for something that can be solved with an echo and a pipe.

Comment: Do I need to store this in the same folder as the .bat file that is currently running?

Comment: @brendensalter - yes, unless you provide a full path to the file, like `<"C:\Users\you\Desktop\I used quotes because it is 2016 and people are still putting spaces in paths for some reason\NoAll.txt"`